# Direct proof for $\sum_{n\le x}\frac{\mu (n)}{n}=O(1)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

It is well-known that $\sum_{n\le x}\frac{\mu (n)}{n}=o(1)$ is equivalent to the prime number theorem. But is there a direct proof for the weaker statement

$$\sum_{n\le x}\frac{\mu (n)}{n}=O(1)?$$

Namely the sum converges? Unfortunately the Dirichlet test doesn't apply here.

Comment: Note that being $O(1)$ only says that the partial sums of the series are bounded, not that the series converges. (since this is not a series of non-negative terms, this is not equivalent to the convergence of the series) This is indeed a much easier statement. It is Theorem $3.13$ in Apostol's analytic number theory book.

Comment: if the series converges the result must be zero since then it is $1/\zeta(1)$ by the usual Abelian style theorems; the hard part is showing convergence (so the Tauberian style converse) not that the sum is zero; boundness follows trivially (even by $1$) from the identity $\sum_{n \le x}\mu(n)[x/n]=1$ which is a simple exercise in convolution of arithmetic functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly $\left|\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\right| \leq 1$ for $x < 2$. For $x \geq 2$, we have that
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \frac{x}{n} = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor + \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \left\{\frac{x}{n}\right\}.$$
Here $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the integer for which $x - 1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$ and $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$.

For the first term, we have that
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor = \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \sum_{m \leq \frac{x}{n}} 1 = \sum_{mn \leq x} \mu(n) = \sum_{a \leq x} \sum_{mn = a} \mu(n).$$
Since $\sum_{mn = a} \mu(n)$ is $1$ if $a = 1$ and $0$ otherwise, we deduce that the first term is equal to $\frac{1}{x}$.

For the second term, since $\mu(n) \in \{-1,0,1\}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that
$$\left|\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \left\{\frac{x}{n}\right\}\right| \leq \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} |\mu(n)| \left\{\frac{x}{n}\right\} \leq \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} \left\{\frac{x}{n}\right\}.$$
Since $\{x\} < x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\{x\} = 0$ if $x$ is an integer, we have that
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \left\{\frac{x}{n}\right\} = \{x\} + \sum_{2 \leq n < x} \left\{\frac{x}{n}\right\} \leq \{x\} + \sum_{2 \leq n < x} 1 = \{x\} + \lfloor x\rfloor - 1 = x - 1.$$
We deduce that the second term is bounded by $\frac{x - 1}{x} = 1 - \frac{1}{x}$.

We conclude that
$$\left|\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\right| \leq \left| \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor\right| + \left| \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) \left\{\frac{x}{n}\right\}\right| \leq \frac{1}{x} + 1 - \frac{1}{x} = 1.$$